# Illegal character in fragment at index 1: #{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']} configurando datasource on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, datasource

I'm following Heroku's guide to configure my datasource through spring xml.

Here's the guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-database_url-in-spring-with-xml-configuration

Here's my config:

```
<bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url"
        value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
    <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
    <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
<bean/>
```

Here`s the error:

```
BeanInstantiationException Could not instantiate bean class java.net.URI Constructor threw exception Illegal character in fragment at index 1: #{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The people following Heroku's documentation and tutorials obviously ...

Which version of Spring are you using? It seems as if Spring didn't replace the SpEL expression with the right value :-/

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume Thanks for helping! It`s a pretty old version actually, it`s and old system i`m trying to migrate to Heroku. I just checked and it`s 2.5.6 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SpEL was only introduced in Spring 3.x+; if you want to use it, you will need to update, fortunately for you Spring is rather good at backward compatibility so you might be lucking and just have to update the dependency. You might also try just the simple `${DATABASE_URL}` syntax, I think the basic resolver goes up to system variables to check values.

Comment: It actually worked using ${DATABASE_URL}! Thanks!
One more question if possible, how should i use it on the other property values?
#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] } = ${dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0]} ?

Comment: Non-SpEL syntax is very limited so you might have to do a few workarounds to compensate for Spring versions lower than 3; I'd assess the effort to move to Spring 4 or 5 before making that decision. For example, you might have to derive your owns URI subclass so you can access the username and password separately (without relying on SpEL) with a syntax that would be `dbUrl.username` (your class would need a getUsername methods that does the split on userInfo).